# ruby NoMethodError undefined method `balance' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

Here is my code and this is the error I am receiving:
`NoMethodError
undefined method 'balance' for nil:NilClass`

I am new to programming and can't seem to figure out the problem.

```
class CheckingAccount < BankAccount
attr_reader :number_of_withdrawals

MAX_FREE_WITHDRAWALS = 3 

def initialize(balance)
  balance = balance
  super(balance) 
  @number_of_withdrawals = 0 
end

def get_free_withdrawal_limit
  MAX_FREE_WITHDRAWALS

end

def transfer(account, amount)
  @other_account = CheckingAccount.new(amount)
  current_balance = @account.balance
  other_balance = @other_account.balance

   if current_balance > amount
     current_balance = @balance - amount 
     other_balance = @balance + amount
  elsif
    current_balance < amount
      "not enought funds available for transfer"
   end
```

Comment: `current_balance = @account.balance`...did you mean `current_balance = account.balance`? I don't see where `@account` is set, but I do see an `account`

Comment: `balance = balance` is superfluous in this case. Additionally `other_balance` seems to be double credited since `@other_account` is instantiated with the given amount and `other_balance` is equal to its balance and then is credited again for the same amount.

Answer (score 2):

The error is within `transfer` method, in this line:

```
current_balance = @account.balance
```

`@account` has not been set anywhere, so it is `nil` and you get a `NoMethodError` when you call `balance` on it.

Maybe you meant `account`, since you are passing it as an argument.